# Ckeditor pasted url links become hyperlinks

Tags: uri, wysiwyg

We have disabled 'Convert URLs into links'.

When you copy a url link from a browser url field like: drupal.org. Your clipboard contains the FQDN: https://www.drupal.org/. When you past this into Ckeditor. It becomes a working hyperlink. This is expected. Can I stop this from happening? We want to allow url links to be pasted/added only through the Ckeditor Linkit module.

Below is an example if you use Linkit external links or if you paste a copied link in. The markup in the Ckeditor source is the same. How can I target the pasted link and strip it out the href attribute?. I thought about adding a link attribute in Linkit to distinguish it. Then use regex that targets href without that attribute and strip out the href.

```
<p><a href="https://www.drupal.org/"https://www.drupal.org/</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="https://www.drupal.org/">https://www.drupal.org/</a>
```

Comment: I guess this is a CKeditor thing, as there is a button `Paste as plain text (Ctrl + Shift + V)` that prevents link conversion.

Comment: Its more likely the "Convert URLs into links" option in the text format you're using under "/admin/config/content/formats"